# Alias host name in springfox api-doc

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

Is there any possibility to set an alias instead of real host name in swagger api-doc? For example, I`d like to see in the doc something like this:

```
"host": "someAlias"
```

Instead of usual localhost:

```
"host": "localhost:<port>"
```

But this alias should not affect the real urls. Is there possibility to map the displayed host name and the real one?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did my provided solution resolve you query ? Were you able to achieve the desired result ? Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no its not supported. You can't make use of hyperlink there. The markdown parsers only work for limited fields like description where you can create links like below:

```
[myApp](http://localhost:8080)
```